# How to turn on voice dictation in Yosemite using a voice command?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is there any way to turn on the built-in voice dictation in Yosemite with a voice command (just like we can do using the voice command "wake up" in Dragon NaturallySpeaking, or "Hey Siri" in Siri)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple says](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203085):

Enable Dictation Commands

Before you can tell your Mac what you want it to do, you need to turn on Dictation Commands.

> When you enable advanced commands, you can also create your own
>   commands by clicking the Add Command (+) button. This lets you link a
>   spoken phrase to an app, a menu item, a keyboard shortcut, or an
>   Automator workflow.